# How to navigate to a section or paragraph in the same page by a link in blazor?

Tags: navigation

```
<a href="#test">Take me to the test paragraph.</a>
<p>Hyperlinks are utilized by a web browser to move from one page to another...</p>
<p>Hyperlinks are utilized by a web browser to move from one page to another...</p>
<p>Hyperlinks are utilized by a web browser to move from one page to another...</p>
<p>Hyperlinks are utilized by a web browser to move from one page to another...</p>
<p id="test">Test paragraph Test paragraph Test paragraph Test paragraph...</p>
```

> I have used this code but when I click on the link, a new page /test (which is empty) opens in the web browser.
> I have searched many websites, all answers are like the method above. What is the problem with my code? I want to navigate just to the test paragraph on the same page. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever get this issue resolved? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Just came across this solution that uses javascript [here](https://mikaberglund.com/creating-anchor-links-in-blazor-applications/)

Comment: Thank you MikeT. I was not using this account long time. Sorry for late response.